# C++ - Two member functions differ by a single function call

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

I am trying to improve my C++ coding and I would like to ask what would be the most efficient and elegant solution of the following problem:

I implemented a class with two member functions. They both fill an array of doubles. The bodies of these functions are identical except one call deep inside. In one of them, I want to call the power function `pow(x[idx], Moment)`. In the other, I would like to call another member function of another object of a different class.

```
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

class Pot {
  public:
    Pot() {}
    virtual double GetPot(const double x) const {return sin(x);}
    virtual ~Pot() {}
}

class BSplOper {
  private:
    const Pot *m_p;
    ... (other private members)
  public:
    BSplOper(const Pot *p) : m_p{p} {}
    virtual ~BSplOper() {}
    void MkMat1();
    void MkMat2();
}

void BSplOper::MkMat1() {
  double val = 0.0;
  for (some nested loops here) {
    ... (some more code - index transformations, etc)
    for (int indx = 0; indx < LargeNumber; indx++) {
      ... (some more nested loops)
      val += pow(x[indx], someconst);
    }
  }
}

void BSplOper::MkMat2() {
  double val = 0.0;
  for (the same code as in MkMat1) {
    ...(the same code as in MkMat1)
    for (int indx = 0; indx < LargeNumber; indx++) {
      ... (the same code as MkMat1)
      val += m_p->GetPot(x[indx]);
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any way to implement this as a single function that would have an argument deciding which function will be called inside? The thing is that this function will be called really many times and its performance is really essential. It is inside a series of the nested loops. Therefore, I do not want to put a condition inside.

I was thinking to use `std::function` as an argument of this member function that would pass the reference to the intended function. However, I am not sure about the overhead of `std::function`.

Would it be more efficient to use a templated member function instead? Something like

```
template<typename F>
void BSplOper::MkMat(F fnx) {
  double val = 0.0;
  for (the same code as in MkMat1) {
    ...(the same code as in MkMat1)
    for (int indx = 0; indx < LargeNumber; indx++) {
      ... (the same code as MkMat1)
      val += (*fnx)(x[indx]);
    }
  }
}
```

In that case, what would be the proper syntax to call it? Or are both these solutions entirely wrong? Thank you for any recommendation.

Comment: If there are only two possibility, you can use a bool named pw for example, and do : `val += pw? pow(x[indx],someconst) : m_p->GetPot(x[indx]);`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. A condition deep inside the nested loop is something I considered better to avoid. I have seen quite negative impact of such thing on the performance in similar applications in the past. Then I think it would be better to have two independent functions.

Comment: You can use a template with this bool. In this case, the compiler will create two functions with no test inside the nested loops

Comment: @TUIlover: Formally speaking, there will be a test, and you need to obey the C++ syntax rules for the test. But practically speaking every decent optimizer will spot this and eliminate the test.

Comment: @MSalters yes that what I meant, I didn’t speak out clearly

Comment: @MSalters: if the `bool` is a template parameter, then that `if` might be promoted to `if constexpr`, so no extra branches.

Comment: @Jarod42: Modern optimizers are already capable enough to remove unused branches of an ordinary `if` or `?:`. The `if constexpr` is more for the C++ language frontend.

Comment: @TUIlover I see it now. Thank you for your advice. I tested all the methods suggested here and they all perform similarly. It seems that, indeed, the optimizer removed the test inside the branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using function pointers has the downside that the compiler might not be able to do all possible optimizations, so you want to give the compiler as much information at compile time as possible.

To do so you would pass that information as a template argument and not as a function argument.

One way to do that would be using `if constexpr` in combination with template parameters.

The following code is just a quick and dirty example of how you could do that. But you might want to use something else then `bool`.

```
struct BSplOper {

    template<bool F>
    void MkMat() {
      double val = 0.0;
      for (some nested loops here) {
        ... (some more code - index transformations, etc)
        for (int indx = 0; indx < LargeNumber; indx++) {
          ... (some more nested loops)
          
          if constexpr(F) {
            val += pow(x[indx], someconst);
          } else {
            val += m_p->GetPot(x[indx]);
          }
        }
      }
    }

    void MkMat1() {
        MkMat<true>();
    }

    void MkMat2() {
        MkMat<false>();
    }
};
```

The `if constexpr` is not the best solution with respect to maintainability and semantics. But how to solve that in the correct way depends on the actual code and value dependencies and liftimes.

Comment: Thank you. It works and it performs very well. Just one more question, if I may: Why would I use anything else than bool here? What is the potential issue with bool? I do not plan to use more than two possible functions to call.

Comment: @michalt The problem with the boolean is maintainability. The boolean as template agrument does not provide much information. Why should `true` result in `val += pow(x[indx], someconst);` and `false` in `val += m_p->GetPot(x[indx]);` it could also be the other way round. If you can find a name for `F` in `template<bool F>` that really expresses this distinction then using a boolean is fine. If you can't find a name then a boolean is a bad decision with respect to readability and maintainability.

Comment: @michalt When writing code, you should always consider whether you can still easily understand the code when you look at it after a long time or if someone else not knowing the code looks at it. And for functions, it should - at least roughly - be clear what the function does by only reading the signature (name and parameters) without taking a close look at its code.

Answer (score 0):

> However, I am not sure about the overhead of `std::function`

It should be similar to a virtual call.

> In that case, what would be the proper syntax to call it?

`val += (*fnx)(x[indx]);` should simply be `val += fnx(x[indx]);`

```
template <typename F>
void BSplOper::MkMat(F fnx) {
  double val = 0.0;
  for (the same code as in MkMat1) {
    ...(the same code as in MkMat1)
    for (int indx = 0; indx < LargeNumber; indx++) {
      ... (the same code as MkMat1)
      val += fnx(x[indx]);
    }
  }
}
```

with call similar to

```
MkMat([&](const auto& elem){ return pow(elem, someconst);});
```

> Or are both these solutions entirely wrong?

They both have pro and cons.

They both handle any functors and not just function pointers.

- `std::function` has runtime overhead, but express clearly expectation.
- template has no overhead, but no expressiveness (duck typing) (concept (C++20) or SFINAE /static_assert might help in that regard if needed). It is template and force visible implementation in header (unless explicit instantiation).

Some propose [`function_view`](https://vittorioromeo.info/index/blog/passing_functions_to_functions.html) (a non owning version of `std::function`, to have expressiveness of `std::function`, without the overhead).
It would even allow to implement the function in cpp as no longer template.